# Getting Storybook react-docgen-typescript-loader to use typescript props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, storybook

I'm trying to use `react-docgen-typescript-loader` to generate my props documentation in Storybook with my TypeScript Props, but it's not populating anything into the `withInfo` addon.

I'm using the TypeScript flavor of create-react-app and I'm following multiple different methods of configuring the `.storybook/webpack.config.js` and nothing seems to work.

Here's what my current config is:

### .storybook/webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = ({ config, mode }) => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
        options: {
          presets: [['react-app', { flow: false, typescript: true }]],
        }
      },
      require.resolve("react-docgen-typescript-loader"),
    ]
  });
  config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx');
  return config;
};
```

### .storybook/config.ts

```
import { configure } from '@storybook/react';
// automatically import all files ending in *.stories.js
const req = require.context('../', true, /.stories.tsx$/);
function loadStories() {
  req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename));
}
configure(loadStories, module);
```

### stories/button.stories.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';
import { withInfo } from '@storybook/addon-info';
import Button from '../src/components/Button';

storiesOf('Button', module)
    .addDecorator(withInfo)
    .add('continue', () => <Button buttonType="submit">Hello Button</Button>, { info: { inline: true } })
    .add('back', () => <Button buttonType="reset">Hello Button</Button>, { info: { inline: true } });
```

#### src/components/Button.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
    buttonType: Button.Type;
}

const Button: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
    const getStyles = (buttonType: string): {color: string} => {
        if (buttonType === 'reset') {
            return { color: 'red' };
        }
        if (buttonType === 'submit') {
            return { color: 'green' };
        }
        return { color: 'green' };
    };

    const { buttonType, children } = props;

    return <button type={buttonType} style={getStyles(buttonType)}>{children}</button>;
};

export default Button;
```

There are currently no issues with this configuration, but I only see this as the info output in Storybook:
[image: storybook screenshot]

Comment: As someone who maintains a large typescript / react storybook react-docgen-typescript  unfortunately makes compile times horrifically slow, because of this i'd recommend just writing out the documentation for your props by hand, this also allows you to write descriptions etc.

Comment: @ShanonJackson That's what I was afraid I'd have to do. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: No problem, i know its sounds painful to have to manually do things (because we are programmers we like to automate things) but it really isnt that bad and not worth trading like 50x slower compiler times over

Comment: You can add descriptions to the props using jsdoc comment formats.  See the code https://imgur.com/G4zGPFt and the output https://imgur.com/nhHePXt

Answer (score 3):

There is some difference in using named imports, this worked for me:

`import React, {FC} from 'react'`
...

`const Button: FC<Props> = (props) => {`

Comment: OMG this was the issue for me. Now I can specify this as an enhancement.

Comment: Can you please expand the explanation was the change from FunctionComponent to FC?